# Proper term for "surity..??"

Tags: meaning, synonyms, vocabulary, dictionaries

What's the proper word for "surity or sure-ness". E.g. "It's a surity that it will happen". I know "assurance" can be used. But is there an even closer term for this..?

Comment: The "proper" word is [**surety**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/surety), defined there by Oxford Dictionaries Online as *the state of being sure or certain of something*. You could have found that by searching for *define **surity***, since I'm sure Google would have given you the same response I got *(Did you mean: define "surety")* The full OED defines your *exact* contextual usage as "now rare".

Comment: Maybe "certainness".

Comment: @Silenus 'certainty' ('certainness' is not a word).

Comment: To keep as close to what you are asking "It's assured that it will happen"

Comment: @Mitch, it's a word by some dictionaries' accounts (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/certainness). But I guess it isn't "proper" in the sense of common. I was mainly trying to be funny by paralleling the markedness of "sure-ness".

Comment: There is no such word.

Answer (score 3):

[Certainty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/certainty):

> The quality of being reliably true:
>
> *'there is a bewildering lack of certainty and clarity in the law'*

and

> A fact that is definitely true or an event that is definitely going to take place:
>
> *'the passing of the act made a general election a certainty'*

Answer (score 1):

Next to @Mark Bannister's *certainty*, consider the informal/colloquial ***cinch***.

> cinch: a certainty to happen: *it's a cinch he'll break the record* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cinch)